# Codeigniter: Pass data from model to controller but didn't get in the view file

Tags: php, codeigniter

I was returning `query->result()` from my model to controller and in the controller I passed the `$data` to the view file but I am not getting any data in the view file.

Here is the **show_model.php** file:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Show_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }
    function get_post_data()
    {
        $query=$this->db->get('posts');
        return $query->result();
    }

}
```

Here is the **show.php** file:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Show extends CI_controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function show_post_data(){

        $this->load->model("Show_model");
        $data['records'] = $this->Show_model->get_post_data();
        $this->load->view('list_view',$data);
    }
}
```

Here is the **show_list.php** view file:

```
<div>
<?php echo "<pre>"; print_r($records); exit; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you try dumping `$data` in your view file please?

Comment: Either there's no data or there's a query error you are not showing us. We can't do anything without them. Check your error reporting in config.php and set it.

Comment: @party-ring, I have done that like you said. But i did not get anything in the print_r.

Comment: try `dump($data); die();` in your controller before `$this->load->view`

Comment: check your query in model before return `echo $this->db->last_query();exit;`

Answer (score 0):

The name of your view is show_list and in the controller you are using list_view
simply replace the code in the controller for displaying the view with

```
function show_post_data(){

    $this->load->model("Show_model");
    $data['records'] = $this->Show_model->get_post_data();
    $this->load->view('show_list',$data);
}
```